# I am trying to avoid duplicates in my lottery rows ie if number 35 is in the first lottery row then it must not be in the second row

Tags: java

I am trying to avoid duplicates in my lottery rows , ie if number 35 is in the first lottery row then it must not be in the second row
I am confused about why I keep on getting duplicates I have added a image that explains my problem better?
What is the best way to go about this probelem?
I have tried to change nt lottoTal = rand.nextInt(35) + 1 to nt lottoTal = rand.nextInt(34) + 1

```
public class LottoCanvas extends BorderPane{

    private Canvas canvas;
    private GraphicsContext gc;
    private Text text;
    private Text textExtra; ///
    private Set<Number> lottorad;
    private Set<Number> lottoradExtra;//
    Random rand;
    public LottoCanvas() { //constructor

        lottorad = new HashSet();
        lottoradExtra = new HashSet();
        rand = new Random();
        canvas = new Canvas(250, 250);
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Button button = new Button("Rita om");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                drawLotto(gc);

            }

        });//end EventHandler

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        text = new Text();
        textExtra = new Text(); //
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(text,textExtra,button);
        drawLotto(gc);
        setCenter(canvas);
        setBottom(vbox);

    }//end constructor
    private void createLottoRad(){

        lottorad.clear(); 
        lottoradExtra.clear(); 


        while (lottorad.size()<7) {
            int lottoTal = rand.nextInt(35) + 1;
            lottorad.add(lottoTal);  
        }
        while (lottoradExtra.size()<4) {
            int lottoTal = rand.nextInt(35) + 1;
            lottoradExtra.add(lottoTal);
        }



    }//end metoden createLottoRad    

    private void drawLotto(GraphicsContext gc) {

        createLottoRad();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int bredd=30;
        int hojd=30;
        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            x += 35; 
            if (i % 7 == 0){
                y += 35;
                x = 0;
            }
            if (lottorad.contains(i+1)){
                gc.setFill(Color.RED);
            }

            if (lottoradExtra.contains(i+1)){
                gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            }

            gc.fillRoundRect(x, y, bredd, hojd , 10, 10);
            gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            gc.fillText("" + (i + 1), x + 10, y + 20);
            gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }

        List myList = new ArrayList(lottorad);
        Collections.sort(myList);
        text.setText(myList.toString());

        List myListExtra = new ArrayList(lottoradExtra);
        Collections.sort(myListExtra);
        textExtra.setText(myListExtra.toString());

    }//end metoden drawLotto
```

}//[enter piture of what i am trying to avoid](https://ibb.co/ydcMbpf)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to avoid duplicates in my lottery rows , ie if number 35 is in the first lottery row then it must not be in the second row I am confused about why I keep on getting duplicates I have added a image that explains my problem better? What is the best way to go about this probelem?

Your current approach is something like this:

- Add random numbers into `lottorad` until there are 7 unique values in it.
- Add random numbers into `lottoradExtra` until there are 4 unique values in it.

The two sets are independent, so there is nothing to prevent from having the same numbers in both. You could add an explicit condition when populating `lottoradExtra` to skip over the number if it's already in `lottorad`, for example:

```
while (lottoradExtra.size() < 4) {
    int lottoTal = rand.nextInt(35) + 1;
    if (lottorad.contains(lottoTal)) {
        continue;
    }
    lottoradExtra.add(lottoTal);
}
```

However, the current approach is flawed, since it's a bit of a waste to do extra loops when the same number keeps coming up repeatedly. In theory, your program might not terminate.

An alternative approach is the build a list of numbers, shuffle it, and just take the first 7 values, and then the first 4 values. That way it's guaranteed there will be no duplicates. For example:

```
List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 35).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(numbers);

lottorad.clear(); 
lottorad.addAll(numbers.subList(0, 7));

lottoradExtra.clear(); 
lottoradExtra.addAll(numbers.subList(7, 11));
```